# Why make tells me the file is up to date when I just updated it

Tags: makefile, dependencies

First of all here is the code :

```
all: file.c

file.c : file.b

file.b:
        echo $@
```

file.c doesn't exist. file.b exists.

My understanding of what is/should be going on when I run the command `make` : It will check if file.c exists. If it does, it won't execute the rule file.c. If it doesn't it will execute the rule file.c

In our case file.c doesn't exist, therefore the rule file.c is executed. Before doing that, it will check if file.b exists. And same story. Except that this time, file.b exists. So it doesn't run the rule file.b

But I thought it should still run the rule file.b even if file.b exists, in the case file.b modification date was changed.

Can you help me understand when/how/what `make` make use of modification dates ? With a very simple code example like I did above, so I understand it better.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16319025/939557  In your case, if `file.b` exists, it will always be considered "up to date" because it has no prerequisites, so there's nothing make can compare it to to see if it's out of date.

Comment: Also, since there's no recipe for building `file.c` there's no way make knows to rebuild it.

Comment: @MadScientist ohh... It took me a few re-read to get it but I get it now, thank you